# In Kartik Gridview when I When I try to resize the browser to less than 767px the column stops wraping

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In Yii2 I added the Kartik Gridview extension and when I When I try to resize the browser to less than 767px the column stops wrapping so if I have say a field that contents alot of text it is all one one line and I can't see it. How to I enable it to keep wrapping the fields even after 767px.

[image]

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
//use kartik\grid\DataColumn;
//use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel backend\models\FaqSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'FAQ';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="faq-index">

<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
<?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

<p>
    <?= Html::a('Create Faq', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    <?= Html::a('Create Faq Type', ['faq-type/create'], 
['class' => 'btn btn-info']) ?>
</p>

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,

    'columns' => [
        ['class' => '\kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],

        [
            'attribute'=>'faq_type_id',
            'value'=>'faqType.type',
        ],
        'question',
        'answer',

        ['class' => '\kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],

    'responsive'=>true,
    'hover'=>true,

]); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: show your view code please and layout too.

Answer (score 0):

try addint content options this way :

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,

    'columns' => [
        ['class' => '\kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],

        [
            'attribute'=>'faq_type_id',
            'value'=>'faqType.type',
        ],
        'question',
        [
            'attribute'=>'answer',
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'word-wrap: normal;'],
        ],

        ['class' => '\kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],

    'responsive'=>true,
    'hover'=>true,

]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out after further searching thru discussion boards etc. I did the following in my GridView and changed

```
 [
        'attribute'=>'answer',
        'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'word-wrap: normal;'],
 ],
```

to this

```
 [
        'attribute'=>'answer',
        'format'=>'raw',
        'value' =>function($data) {
            return '<div class="kv-expanded-content">'.
                                  $data- >answer.'</div>';},
 ],
```

and then adding the following to my CSS file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.kv-expanded-content {
    width:100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; 
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; 
    white-space: -pre-wrap; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
'responsiveWrap' => false,
```

after

```
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
```

Comment: You need to explain why that would solve the problem